# What is a Thyristor Switched Series Capacitor (TSSC)?

Tags: control, power-electronics, power-engineering, thyristor, reactive-power

I'm struggling to understand the physical difference between the Thyristor Switched Series Capacitor (TSSC)  and the Thyristor Controlled Series Capacitor (TCSC).

From [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sxKY60Q83I8C&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=TCSC+vs+TSSC&source=bl&ots=Yq2ChdwgnB&sig=rIgyF49P3PwcfOobdja6UZE5BQ4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sbF3VL_LKsflaO2YgaAE&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=TSSC&f=false), I understand that a  TSSC permits discreet control of capacitive reactance, while TCSC permits continuous control of capacitive and inductive reactance. The book also mentions that TSSC is more comonly employed, however, when continous control is desired, the TCSC is employed.

[This paper](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs-wm/43897.pdf) gives a good outline of what a TCSC is and how the thrysitors are controled. The diagram for a TCSC is shown below:

[image]

However I cannot find a diagram for a TSSC. **How does the system differ from the TSCS? And what would the diagram of the TSSC look like?**